# consuming SOAP web services over android

Tags: java, android, hibernate, soap

I have an java EE web server running `struts 2, hibernate and spring frameworks`. The web application is simple online file storage solution with encryption. Now I want to expose my methods via a SOAP web service so that I can use that in my android application. I have the WSDL for my web service. I followed a tutorial and come to know that we can use java `wsimport` tool to generate java classes from WSDL.
 Can I use that java classes to use in my android application So that my application can communicate with the remote server?
 
I am using hibernate for database operation so there would be hibernate entity classes that are returned. I am thinking I can have simple `POJO` classes in android application instead of hibernate entity classes.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Zeus can I use classes generated by wsimport command in android application

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this, I dont think it will work out of the box. KSoap2-android project library might help you .

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-android/index.html